# Ansible ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAM Mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: ansible, yaml

I've gone over this YML code for hours. It's simple, but I can't see why I'm getting this error. Can anyone point me in the right direction or explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

```
- name: Copy the db_config file
  hosts: all
      - name: Copy the db_config file
        become: yes
        copy:
        src: db_config.ini
        dest: /home/labdb/stream/config.ini
        owner: lab1
        group: lab1
      when: lab_enabled == true lab_redis_data_volume:
```

I tried adjusting my spaces/tabs, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

The value of a key in a YAML dictionary can be a list:

```
somekey:
  - item 1
  - item 2
```

A dictionary:

```
somekey:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

Or a scalar value, like a string or an integer:

```
somekey: somevalue
```

In your example, you appear to be trying to make the value of `hosts` be two of those things: both a scalar value and a list. You can't do that. If you take a look at an [example playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution), you'll see that in your example you're missing the `tasks` key. What you have should be written like this:

```
- name: Copy the db_config file
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Copy the db_config file
      become: yes
      copy:
      src: db_config.ini
      dest: /home/labdb/stream/config.ini
      owner: lab1
      group: lab1
    when: lab_enabled == true lab_redis_data_volume:
```

In other words, you have a Playbook, which is a list of Plays. A Play is a dictionary, and the value of the `tasks` key in that dictionary is a list of Tasks.

Comment: Oh, this makes so much sense, thank you!!

Comment: look up for `ansible-lint`, it is a tool that can help you with static analysis of your ansible code, find that kind of errors and propose ways to fix them

Comment: "Or a scalar value", neat way to describe it. +1